# Error in referencing two dimensional array in function search for pattern

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

template <int num_rows, int num_cols, int patR, int patC>
int search_for_pattern(int (&grid)[num_rows][num_cols], int indexR, int indexC, int (&pattern)[patR][patC]){
    for(int m = 0, i = indexR; m < patR && i < num_rows; m++, i++){
        for(int n = 0, j = indexC; n < patC && j < num_cols; n++, j++){
            if(grid[i][j] != pattern[m][n]){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){


  int T;
        cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int R, C;
        cin>>R>>C;
        string* arry = new string[R];
        int** int_arry = new int*[R];
        for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            int_arry[i] = new int[C];

        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
           getline(cin>>ws, arry[i]); //cin >> ws gets rid of leading whitespace
                                       //first so that getline won't think that it's already
                                       //reached the end of the line
                                      //It doesn't seem to take the above input string
        }
       for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arry[i].length(); j++){
            int_arry[i][j] = (int)(arry[i][j] - '0');
            //cout<<int_arry[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        //cout<<endl;
       }

        //Pattern Array input 
        int pattern_R, pattern_C;
        cin>>pattern_R>>pattern_C;

        string* pattern_arry = new string[pattern_R];
        int** int_pattern_arry = new int*[pattern_R];
        for(int i = 0; i < pattern_R; ++i)
            int_pattern_arry[i] = new int[pattern_C];

        for(int i = 0; i < pattern_R; i++){
           getline(cin>>ws, pattern_arry[i]); 
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pattern_R; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < pattern_arry[i].length(); j++){
            int_pattern_arry[i][j] = (int)(pattern_arry[i][j] - '0');
           // cout<<int_pattern_arry[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        //cout<<endl;
       }

        int flag = 0, patternTrue = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= R - pattern_R; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= C - pattern_C; j++){
                if(int_arry[i][j] == int_pattern_arry[i][j]){
                        flag = 1;
                        patternTrue = search_for_pattern(int_arry, i, j, int_pattern_arry);
                        if(patternTrue){
                            cout<<"YES";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            if(patternTrue) break;
            cout<<endl;

        }

        if(flag == 0){
            cout<<"NO";
        }

       //Delete Grid 
       for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        delete [] int_arry[i];
    }
    delete [] int_arry;
    delete [] arry;

        //Delete Pattern
        for(int i = 0; i < pattern_R; ++i) {
        delete [] int_pattern_arry[i];
    }
    delete [] int_pattern_arry;
    delete [] pattern_arry;
        cout<<endl;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

While trying to compile the above program in c++, I am having trouble passing the 2d array int_pattern_arry and pattern_arry. I am trying to pass the 2d array as a reference, but I can't seem to proceed any further. How can I pass these 2 arrays to the function search_for_pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use non-const values that are unknown at compile time to initialize your template function.

Templates are always created at compile time and all required data must be available then.

Adjust your search function this way:

```
int search_for_pattern(int** grid, int grid_rows, int grid_cols, int** pattern, int pat_rows, int pat_cols, int indexR, int indexC) {
    for (int m = 0, i = indexR; m < pat_rows && i < grid_rows; m++, i++) {
        for (int n = 0, j = indexC; n < pat_cols && j < grid_cols; n++, j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] != pattern[m][n]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And the call this way:

```
patternTrue = search_for_pattern(int_arry, R, C, int_pattern_arry, pattern_R, pattern_C, i, j);
```

Comment: This reasoning isn't really the answer to the question. Still, the proposed code is valid (if suboptimal).

Answer (score 1):

`int_arry` is not a two-dimensional array of `int`s. It is an array of `int*`s.

These are not the same thing.

**`int[x][y]:`**

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| int | int | int | int | int | int |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
\___________/
 \    x
  \_________________________________/
                 y*x
```

**`int(*)[y]`:**

```
/                    \
+------+------+------+
| int* | int* | int* |
+------+------+------+
    |     |       ↓
    |     | +-----+-----+
    |     | | int | int |
    |     | +-----+-----+
    |     ↓
    | +-----+-----+
    | | int | int |
    | +-----+-----+
    ↓
+-----+-----+
| int | int |
+-----+-----+
```

As you can see, the two are completely different.

If you really want a dynamically-allocated "two-dimensional array", I suggest a `std::vector<int>` of size *x×y*, with two-dimensional access wrapped around it. It'll be much easier.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to use the concept of allocating a 2d dynamic array and deallocating it.

Comment: @Sitansu: You cannot allocate a 2D dynamic array; at least, not with both dimensions determined at runtime.

Comment: I understand the use of vector here would have been better.. I am trying this out using vector again. Thanks!